# How to read and write in content control rich text of MS Word in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, window

I have a table in ms word , which contains a content control Rich Text (Which can be added by using developers ribbon) in cells.
I want to read and write text in Rich Text using window c# .

I was trying to read fields by
wd.ActiveDocument.FormFields.Count.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

You can use office interop  api s to explore word files.

Look into the following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Comment: Rajesh Subramanian : Your link gives access to Excel not MS word , I am still awaiting for solution of my problem .

Comment: the same way u can access winword programmatically by adding Interop.Word. Just search it over internet and try. Thank you.

Comment: Try following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Very urgent and very little detail

You don't say Forms or WPF

Not going to read and write to MS Word in .NET without a 3rd party control to my knowledge

FlowDocument has rich formatting but is limited to WPF.

RichTextBox can be used to edit a FlowDocument.

[FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx)

Comment: Its window form application without using any third party tool

Comment: Rutwik Reddy : Initially i had table , In table its very easy to read and write. But now i have richtext inside table cells .

Comment: Blam: FlowDocument is not helpfull for me .

Comment: One: not the place to reply to Rutwik. Two: add Forms Tag  Three: what have you done?   Richtext inside table cells is not nearly enough detail.

Comment: Blam:Richtext inside table cells means open your MS Word go to developrs button , from there you can add richtext to your document.

Comment: If you have updates to the question put em IN the question.  And fix your tags.  I see you are new to SO. But you need to show more effort,